# DLE. При добавлении sql запроса в show,full выводится только 1 запись в блоке.

Tags: php, dle

Есть вот такой кусок кода:

```
$rel_full_link = $config['http_home_url'] . date( 'Y/m/d/', $related['date'] ) . $related['alt_name'] . ".html";
                        }

                    } else {

                        $rel_full_link = $config['http_home_url'] . "index.php?newsid=" . $related['id'];

                    }


                     $iconsr=$db->super_query("SELECT icon FROM " . PREFIX . "_usersoft_file WHERE news_id='".$related['id']."' AND moderation='1' AND type='application' AND zip='0' ORDER BY versioncode DESC LIMIT 1");


                    $tpl2->set( '{icon}','/uploads/files/icon/'.$iconsr['icon'].'');
                    $tpl2->set( '{title}', strip_tags( stripslashes( $related['title'] ) ) );
```

Если я оставлю

```
$iconsr=$db->super_query("SELECT icon FROM " . PREFIX . "_usersoft_file WHERE news_id='".$related['id']."' AND moderation='1' AND type='application' AND zip='0' ORDER BY versioncode DESC LIMIT 1");
```

То в блоке похожих записей выводится только 1 запись, ну а если убираю - то столько, сколько нужно...

Подскажите, как в dle это побороть?=)

Answer (score 1):

> $iconsr=$db->super_query("SELECT icon FROM " . PREFIX .
>   "_usersoft_file WHERE news_id='".$related['id']."' AND moderation='1'
>   AND type='application' AND zip='0' ORDER BY versioncode DESC **LIMIT
>   1**");

`LIMIT 1` же.

Comment: Не. 
Это не то. Там хоть лимит 100 поставь - где то цикл есть... Вот не могу найти его.